# How to use global variables in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

I am developing an application in codeigniter containing different modules e.g buyer, seller, public. All these modules use same header file. I want a global variable declared in buyer, seller and public controller so that when I load views of one module this variable should help customizing parts of header for seller depending upon its value. Same goes for buyer and public modules.

I want to ask what is the way to have a variable declared at controller scope and then use its value in its views. I have tried declaring and assigning its value in constructor but I get undefined variable error when loading the views. I also tried this way:

```
class Seller extends CI_Controller {

public $pagetype="seller";
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

But I still get undefined variable error. 
I can pass value of page type when loading view but I have to do that for each view, which is bad and cumbersome way because I have around 25-30 views in each controller.

Any help?

Comment: You may require globals http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller you can make data globally available in the view layer using this

```
$this->load->vars($data);
```

where $data is an array of key => values.  you could put this in your constructor, or parent constructor

Answer (score 0):

Consider making your own class - look into Singleton or Registry design patterns... but also read this: [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

you could assign the main CodeIgniter object to a variable and then use `load->get_var($key)` to get the view variable.

```
function something() {
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $myvar = $ci->load->get_var(‘myvar);
}
```